# NSFetchedResultController for an Entity and its relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an Entity `Person`. Person has three relationships to Entity `ObjectA`, `ObjectB`, and `ObjectC`.

Can I use an `NSFetchedResultController` to sort them by type? So section 0 would be `ObjectA`'s, section 1 would be `ObjectB`'s, and section 3 would be `ObjectC'`s? And further, can i sort them by name?

Or do I use 3 different datasources (either load them into an array or 3 different `NSFetchResultController`'s)?

Answer (score 1):

An `NSFetchedResultController` can only fetch one entity type at a time, so assuming `ObjectA`, `ObjectB`, and `ObjectC` are different entity types, then you'll need three NSFRCs.

If they are three different entity types, you might consider putting them under an abstract entity. Then you could create one NSFRC for that type (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327835/core-data-abstract-entity-in-fetch-request)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hesitant to do it but glad I did, it just makes more sense to use inheritance and simplified a couple of things (I did not use abstract cause I'm not entirely sure what that is or what it does yet). Now just gotta learn how to group them.